# An alternative to "Granger Causality" test when (short) time series are not stationary?

Tags: r, time-series, causality, granger-causality

I have two short time series (x and y), and I wish to find out if x "effects" (is correlated with) y.  Obviously, since the two are time series, using a simple correlation is the wrong way to go.

I would have used Grenger test, but when checking it appears that the series do not seem to be stationary (nor when I take their diffs).

**Any suggestion on how to deal with such a case?**

Here is a sample code with my data:

[image]

```
# reading data
DATA <- structure(list(year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994), y = c(-801.87, 
-489.87, -333.87, -258.87, 475.13, -207.87, 451.13, 389.13, -172.87, 
318.13, 252.13, 105.13, 70.13, 57.13, 147.13), x = c(-248.53, 
-143.53, -69.53, -41.53, -3.53, 27.47, 33.47, 35.47, 60.47, 56.47, 
57.47, 60.47, 53.47, 53.47, 68.47)), .Names = c("year", "y", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = c("cast_df", "data.frame"
))

with(DATA, cor(y, x))

# plot's the series:
with(DATA, plot.ts(data.frame(y, x)))

# grangertest signif:
require(lmtest)
with(DATA, grangertest(x,y))

# stationary?
with(DATA, PP.test(x)) # no 
with(DATA, PP.test(y)) # maybe
with(DATA, PP.test(diff(x))) # maybe
with(DATA, PP.test(diff(y))) # no
```

Comment: It is difficult with such a short series to distinguish between the underlying temporal trend and x. [Here is an example](http://www.christophpfeiffer.org/2012/11/07/toda-yamamoto-implementation-in-r/) of VAR in R that should be helpful. Visually, I'm skeptical differencing is appropriate. Do you expect `y` to also have an effect on `x`, `x` is a near perfect example of an AR(1) process?

Comment: Hi Andy,  it could also well be that y has an effect on x.  So you think the VAR model is the best option?

Comment: It is perhaps your best option, but with so little data it will hardly be any more convincing than just showing the two line graphs simultaneously as you have already done, IMO.